# How java deals with references to a generic type

Tags: java, generics, reference, wildcard

How java stores and deals with generic information with references.

`List<A>` is a subtype of `List<?>`. Please explain above statement. How inheritance works with references to a generic object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 0):

"`A` is a subtype of `B`" means that everywhere where type `B` is necessary, you may use the type `A` as well. In your statement `List<?>` type is "list of objects of any type, we don't care about it" and `List<A>` type is "list of objects of type `A`". Thus it should be obvious that everywhere we need "list of objects of any type" we can also use "list of objects of type `A`".

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

> The unbounded wildcard type is specified using the wildcard character (?), for example, List. This is called a list of unknown type. There are two scenarios where an unbounded wildcard is a useful approach:
>
> 1. If you are writing a method that can be implemented using functionality provided in the Object class.
> 2. When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter.

Moving from **unbounded**(?) to **bounded** type() is moving away from **Generic** to **Specific** entity.

let's go through my own example.

1. Earth, a planet have **Living Things**
2. **Animals**, **Trees** are some of the **Living things**
3. **Humans** are animal with 2 legs and 2 hands
4. **Men & Women** are two types of humans.

If you have ? in List, you can apply List to **Living things**. But if you want your list to contain only Humans or **Men** or **Women**, you will decide bounded type  as per your need.

As you move from generic to specific : List  < ? > , List < Living things >, List < Humans >, List< Men >, you are applying more specific things to your entity.

**Tree is a Living thing like Human or Men but it can't have 2 legs and 2 hands like Men and it can't think.**

You have to decide at which specific level, you want to bind the entity to specific type.