# What is <?> in java?

Tags: java, android

I have this code in Android project

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ....
```

What does the `AdapterView<?>` mean? Like any type of AdapterView generics? What if I call some func on `parent` that has type in `<T>` either as param or return value?

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117941/how-java-deals-with-references-to-a-generic-type/33122439#33122439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an example of an unbounded wildcard, AdapterView indicates a list which has an unknown object type. Methods which take such a list as a parameter will accept any type of list as argument.
If you read from such list, then it will return objects of type Object.